# Using if statements within a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to use if statements to categorize numbers within a range as either hot, cold, or pleasant temperatures but it is not working. Here is the code i have:

```
cold = 0
hot = 0
pleasant = 0

temp = int(input("Temperature C (-500 to stop): "))

while temp >= -499:
 temp = int(input("Temperature C (-500 to stop): "))
 if temp > 28:
    hot = hot + 1
 elif 28 > temp > 17:
    pleasant = pleasant + 1
 elif temp < 18:
    cold = cold + 1

print('Cold days:        {}'.format(cold))
print('Pleasant days:    {}'.format(pleasant))
print('Hot days:         {}'.format(hot))
```

------- Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what "not working" means?

Comment: Define "not working"... What is your input? What is your output? What output do you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?". In addition, your "pleasant" condition should probably be: `elif 29 > temp > 17:`

Comment: By not working i mean it does not properly count the number of days for each category, for example if i enter 30 (which should be categorized as a hot day), and than enter -500 to end the loop, it will display 1 cold day, and 0 hot or pleasant days.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for input again only at the end of your while loop, else your 2nd input is going to overwrite the first one (the one before the while loop). Here is the fixed code:

```
cold = 0
hot = 0
pleasant = 0

temp = int(input("Temperature C (-500 to stop): "))

while temp >= -499:
 if temp > 28:
    hot = hot + 1
    print("hot updated")
 elif 28 > temp > 17:
    pleasant = pleasant + 1
    print("pleasant updated")
 elif temp < 18:
    cold = cold + 1
    print("cold updated")
 temp = int(input("Temperature C (-500 to stop): "))

print('Cold days:        {}'.format(cold))
print('Pleasant days:    {}'.format(pleasant))
print('Hot days:         {}'.format(hot))
```